# How can I have a different shape of icon for the icon launcher?

Tags: android

Is it possible to have a circle version of the icon app and a square version?
If yes, how? Because from **Android Studio>Image Assets**, I've generated a squared, and a circled version, but I only see the squared version in my emulator (I see the icon with the android).

In the mipmap folder, I have two different *XML* files; one generated with a squared png icon, and the other with the circled png.

```
ic_launcher.xml
ic_launcher_round.xml
```

But this doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Icon Type : Launcher Icons(Adaptive & legacy) in

[image: Image Asset Stuio]

Comment: Like i have writed in my post, i already used that tools but I couldn't get round icon for `ic_launcher_round` and squared icon for `ic_launcher`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to register both icons in the manifest

```
    <application
    ....
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    ....>
```

The icon you see in the emulator or on your phone depends on the android version running.
Version 6 and below (API 23 and lower) will show the square version.
Android 7 versions show the round and beginning with Android 8 you can use the [adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive)

Comment: I did so, but the emulator shows me the default android icon.

Comment: and what android version is running on your emulator?

Comment: API 28 device in my emulator. When i try to have 2 different icon for round and squared i see an icon with the droid and green backgroung.

Comment: You see round icons for Android 7 ONLY! For Android 8+ you need to create an adaptive icon or you will see the standard-squared version. The round icons where a short intermezzo for version 7 only - they switched to adaptive afterwards (I already wrote that in my answer above). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

On your application manifest.xml please add

```
<application  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" >
```